# Which Fragment will be replaced when use fragmentTransaction.replace?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="[URL]http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android[/URL]"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <fragment
android:name="fragments"
android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"/>

 <fragment
android:name="fragments"
android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So I have 2 Fragment in my Activity
And when I add a Fragment in android.R.id.content, which Fragment will be added?
My Mainactivity.java:

```
if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
 LM_Fragment lm_Fragment = new LM_Fragment();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, lm_Fragment);
 }else{
 PM_Fragment pm_Fragment = new PM_Fragment();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_Fragment);
 }

 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }
```

LM_Fragment and PM_Fragment is used for Landscape mode and Portrait mode. And when I use `fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, lm_Fragment);`
It will be added in 1 in 2 fragment which I specified in xml, but where lm_fragment or pm_fragment? Thank you!

Comment: The problem is explained, here, in this blog post from 2011.  https://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/programmatic-and-layout-fragments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is replace method signature

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
```

You don't have such id `android.R.id.content` in your layout. 
Thing is that you're using static fragments. But you need dynamic. Replace both fragment tag with single FrameLayout with id=android.R.id.content. Or better use your own id. E.g. "fragment_container", and then call

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, lm_Fragment);
```

and

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, pm_Fragment);
```